# javascript not able to hide button inside <h:form>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to hide my icon/button on submission of dialog box...My code stops working when i place my icon/button inside `<h:form>`

This is code for my icon

```
<h:outputLink id="loginLink" value="javascript:void(0)"
                onclick="dlg.show()">
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/logo.png" />
</h:outputLink>
```

this is code for dialog box

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Login" widgetVar="dlg">
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Login"
                oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

now this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args) {
        dlg.hide();
    jQuery('#loginLink').fadeOut();
    alert("This is working fine");
}
</script>
```

Everything works fine this way.. `alert("This is working fine");` is working fine and my icon also gets fade out....

But when I place my icon inside `<h:form></h:form>` icon doesn't fade out(Script is working fine but unable to reach my icon inside `<h:form>`

Ex:

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputLink id="loginLink" value="javascript:void(0)"
            onclick="dlg.show()">
        <p:graphicImage value="/images/logo.png" />
    </h:outputLink>
</h:form>
```

This way I am facing problem :(

P.S : using `<h:form>` is must for me as I am going to place my code in `<p:menuitem>` which needs to be placed inside `<h:form>`

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with jsf to provide a working example, but this type of renaming of components exists in asp .net... these posts describe solutions that may be helpful:  http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/02/jsf-working-with-component-ids.html, http://java.dzone.com/articles/jsf-20-clientid-jquery

Comment: Adding the `<h:form>` will prefix all element ids, see [How to get element from javascript in JSF 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527071).

Comment: @Mohit Saluja: Is it necessary (or something specific) to use `<p:commandButton>` ? You may try `<p:commandLink>`

Comment: @A.K that doesn't matter....i think problem will be same even in that case....

Comment: @Mohit Saluja: I don't think so, have you tried?

Comment: @A.K i have tried this....using `<p:commandLink/>` doesn't makes any difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stead of hiding the full form you can hide only the element in the form only using the following:

```
<h:form id="loginForm">
    <h:outputLink id="loginLink" />
</h:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args) {
        dlg.hide();
        $("[id='loginForm:loginLink']").fadeOut();
    }
</script>
```

In the above example jQuery escapes the ":" in the id.

You can also make use of JSF's binding:

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputLink binding="#{loginLink}"/>
</h:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args) {
        dlg.hide();
        $("[id='#{loginLink.clientId}']").fadeOut();
    }
</script>
```

Pick your choice ;-)

Comment: thanks for your answer.....i have already got one solution almost same as yours....
i had tried somthing similar to your first one code but skipped `id=` in  ` $("[id='loginForm:loginLink']").fadeOut();` so i think that was the reason it didn't worked for me..

and in your second answer i had also tried one similar to that but i use `<h:outputLink id="loginLink"` instead of `<h:outputLink binding="#{loginLink}"/>`...so that one method also not worked for me.....

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for replying :)
Below code working fine for me

```
<h:form id="loginForm">
```

and in javaScript

`jQuery('#loginForm').fadeOut();`

(#id of `form` in place of #id of `button/link`)

This way i can hide my complete form which is having icon/button...

Actually when i am placing my button/link,icon inside `<h:form>` id of button is not visible to javaScript

When i am giving id to `<h:form>` and hiding whole form instead of single component(button) it works fine for me :)

I will try this in `<p:menutem/>` hope this works fine there...

Comment: Your solution is a workaround it doesn't take care of the problem itself. Please see my answer for a solid fix. ;-)

Comment: yes you are right hiding whole `<h:form/>` didn't worked for me in case of primefaces `<p:menuitem/>` as i needed to kept it in a `<h:form>`.....than i came with a solution i have used javaScript and hided the only the `<p:menuitem/>`...its almost same as your answer... thanks for your answer..